# Count Vowels from a word list and return the number as a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I just want to define a function, number_of_vowels, that returns the number of vowels in a string.

My code is below:

```
vowels='aeiou'
def number_of_vowels(word):
    return[len([letter.lower() for letter in word if letter in vowels])]
names = ["Ben", "April", "Zaber", "Alexis", "McJagger", "J.J.", "Madonna"]
number_of_vowels(names)
```

I only got [0] in my result. Not sure why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are feeding a list but your logic is appropriate for a single string only:

```
number_of_vowels('Bean')  # [2]
```

You need to either adjust the input to your function, or modify your function to calculate the number of vowels for each element of your list. Since you wish the output to be a list of numbers, I assume you're looking for the second option.

To do this, just add an extra `for` clause in your list comprehension:

```
def number_of_vowels(words):
    return [len([letter for letter in word if letter.lower() in vowels]) \
            for word in words]

number_of_vowels(names)  # [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3]
```

However, note the intermediary lists are not required. You can use `sum` with a generator expression instead, taking advantage of the fact `True == 1` and `False == 0`:

```
vowels = set('aeiou')

def number_of_vowels(words):
    return [sum(letter.lower() in vowels for letter in word) for word in words]

number_of_vowels(names)  # [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3]
```

Notice a couple of further changes to improve your algorithm:

1. Check for `letter.lower() in vowels` instead of just creating a list of lower-case letters. Otherwise vowels as capital letters, e.g. in "April", will be ignored.
2. Convert your vowels to `set` for O(1) lookup complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `regular expressions` and `list comprehension` for this task.

```
import re
names = ["Ben", "April", "Zaber", "Alexis", "McJagger", "J.J.", "Madonna"]
[len(re.findall('a|e|i|o|u', name.lower())) for name in names]
>>> [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine why you're getting `[0]`. You're returning a list with a single element that is the `len` of the list generated by your list comprehension `[letter.lower() for letter in word if letter in vowels]`.

What is this list comprehension doing? It's creating lowercase words for each word in your word list but only if it's in `vowels`. Since none of the words in your word list are `in aeiou`, this list is empty.

You probably meant to write it as:

```
def number_of_vowels(word):
    return len([letter.lower() for letter in word if letter.lower() in vowels])

names = ["Ben", "April", "Zaber", "Alexis", "McJagger", "J.J.", "Madonna"]    
vowel_count = [number_of_vowels(name) for name in names]
```

If not, you can certainly refer to @jpp's solution which is cool.